# Property that defines Quadric Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, quadrics

The book < Geometry and the Imagination >  (written by David Hilbert) introduces a property of a Quadric Surface  without a proof.

> Property : The cone consisting of all the tangents from a fixed point to a quadric cuts every plane in a conic, and the points of contact of this cone with the surface form a conic.
>
> Moreover, the quadrics are the only surfaces having any of these properties.

It was easy to prove the property itself, but i found it difficult to prove that it is a sufficient condition for a surface to be a quadric. (the statement starting with "Moreover, ...") I would like to know the proof of this statement.